# Converting json to yaml in Terraform

Tags: terraform

How can we generate an yaml out from a json

```
{
   "users":[
      {
         "name":"rock",
         "age":33,
         "city":"paris"
      },
      {
         "name":"austin",
         "age":45,
         "city":"greece"
      }
   ]
}
```

Expected output with a additional field with random password

```
users:
  - key: 'user[0].name'
    value: rock
  - key: 'user[0].age'
    value: '33'
  - key: 'user[0].city'
    value: paris
  - key: 'user[0].password'
    value: '5]L+J7rA*<7+:PO6'
  - key: 'user[1].name'
    value: austin
  - key: 'user[1].age'
    value: '45'
  - key: 'user[1].city'
    value: greece
  - key: 'user[1].password'
    value: P=x&385YGMI0?!Is
```

The files are used only on a local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straight conversion from JSON to YAML would involve just passing the result of [`jsondecode`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/jsondecode.html) to [`yamlencode`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/yamlencode.html).

However, the meat of your question seems to not be about conversion between serialization formats but rather about transforming from a typical nested data structure into a flattened structure using a compound key syntax.

Transforming from a multi-level structure into a single-level structure is a good job for [`flatten`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/flatten.html):

```
locals {
  users = flatten([
    for idx, u in local.users : [
      for k, v in u : {
        key   = "user[${idx}].${v}"
        value = v
      }
    ]
  ])
}
```

The result would be a Terraform value corresponding to the data structure you illustrated in YAML:

```
[
  {
    key   = "user[0].name"
    value = "rock"
  },
  {
    key   = "user[0].age"
    value = 33
  },
  # ...etc...
]
```

You can then pass the result to [`yamlencode`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/yamlencode.html) to produce the YAML serialization of that data structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [file function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/file.html) of terraform to read the content of your json.

You can then use [jsondecode](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/jsondecode.html) to decode/represent the string as json.

The last step is to use , [yamlencode](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/yamlencode.html) function to encode returned json representation in yaml format.

Please see below terraform config.

```
locals {
  test = yamlencode(jsondecode(file("${path.module}/test.json")))
}

output "test" {
  value = local.test
}
```

The result from the above tf config is as below

```
Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

test = "users":
- "age": 33
  "city": "paris"
  "name": "rock"
- "age": 45
  "city": "greece"
  "name": "austin"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
locals {
  users = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/user.json"))
}

resource "random_string" "password" {
 count =  length(local.users.users)
 length = 16
 special = true
}

output "pass" {
    value = random_string.password
  
}

locals {
  user_flat = yamlencode(flatten([for i,j  in local.users.users:[
   for k,v in j : {
       key = "user.[${i}].${k}"
       "value" = v
        } 
      ]
    ]
  )
)
  out = yamlencode({"users"= local.user_flat}) 
}

output "Desired_output" {
    value = local.out
}
```

Try this code.

```
Outputs:

Desired_output = <<EOT
"users": |
  - "key": "user.[0].age"
    "value": 23
  - "key": "user.[0].city"
    "value": "barcelona"
  - "key": "user.[0].name"
    "value": "john"
  - "key": "user.[1].age"
    "value": 29
  - "key": "user.[1].city"
    "value": "london"
  - "key": "user.[1].name"
    "value": "bob"

EOT
pass = [
  {
    "id" = "XEXj*svXm@d&_%Fn"
    "keepers" = tomap(null) /* of string */
    "length" = 16
    "lower" = true
    "min_lower" = 0
    "min_numeric" = 0
    "min_special" = 0
    "min_upper" = 0
    "number" = true
    "override_special" = tostring(null)
    "result" = "XEXj*svXm@d&_%Fn"
    "special" = true
    "upper" = true
  },
  {
    "id" = "Ews%V%Xk[YBd]D_M"
    "keepers" = tomap(null) /* of string */
    "length" = 16
    "lower" = true
    "min_lower" = 0
    "min_numeric" = 0
    "min_special" = 0
    "min_upper" = 0
    "number" = true
    "override_special" = tostring(null)
    "result" = "Ews%V%Xk[YBd]D_M"
    "special" = true
    "upper" = true
  },
]
```